# ggplot without the use of subset

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe, subset, r-factor

I'm using ggplot2 with the faceting option to plot several results of a data.frame.

It's a data.frame with three factors :

- participant (N) with 6 levels;
- condition (C) with 6 levels;
- stimuli (S) with 10 conditions.

I plot the results of one participants in one condition using the subset function and then I facet with ggplot. However, I was wondering if there was an easier solution in ggplot2?

Thanks for any help, I'm currently learning R and ggplot2.

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you post sample data and code.  See this question and answers for tips: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/602276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to ask how to set up a two-way facet. I'm going to guess that 'stimuli is your predictor variable.

One way is like this:

```
ggplot( mydata, aes( x = stimuli, y = my.response) +

        facet_wrap( condition ~ participant) +

        geom_line()
```

or

```
        geom_point()
```

Comment: OK thank you, but i wander how i can plot that for only one defined condition?

Comment: You can remove one of the variables in the facet_wrap statement, but some sample code showing what you've tried so far would be helpful.